# How can we find regression coefficients for time series data

Tags: regression, time-series

I have to find regression coefficients for my time series data set. One of my friends told that it is not possible to use the ordinary least squares method since the observations are not independent. Which method I can use?

Comment: the answer depends on the model specifics such as 1) what are you currently assuming for the error term 2) are you using lagged values of the dependent variable as independent variables  and probably many other things that I can't think of right now.

Comment: You could use Ordinary Least squares but must ensure that the time series is free of serial correlation.

Comment: Thank you both for your valuable reply, it is very useful. It is better if I get more clarification. I have some doubts , (1) which analysis can use if there is lagged values of dependent variable as independent variables? (2) What do you exactly meant by serial correlation, here?

Comment: Serial correlation is correlation between successive members of the series.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know where people get the idea that one cannot use least squares to fit time series models. Not only *can* one use least squares, oftentimes one *should* use least squares to fit these models. It is not just me saying this; see, for example, [the definitive reference in the field](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540262393), or just [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression#Estimation_of_the_regression_parameters). Least squares estimation has nothing to do whatsoever with the type of data being analyzed, whether it is correlated or not, since it is fundamentally an application of the normal equation from linear algebra. The *only* property of data that prevents least squares estimation is that of [perfect multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity), and if this is occurring in your data, there are other, larger problems at work.

Since you want some practical advice on how to estimate linear time series models, I will give you some. Suppose that you want to estimate the stable $N$-dimensional vector autoregressive process
$$
\begin{aligned}
y_t = c + \sum_{p=1}^P A_py_{t-p} + u_t,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $u_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$, and $A_p,\ \Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ with $\Sigma$ positive semidefinite (as a covariance matrix must be).
We suppose there is data for this model for all $t \in \{1,2,...,T\}$.
What we do to solve this problem using ordinary least squares is write the process in [matrix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_matrix_notation_of_a_VAR(p)):
$$
Y = XB + U,
$$
where $Y = (y_p,y_{p+1},...,y_T)^T$, $B = (c, A_1,...,A_p)^T$,
$$
X = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & y_{p-1} & \cdots & y_0\\
1 & y_p & \cdots & y_1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & y_{T-1} & \cdots & y_{T-p}
\end{pmatrix},
$$ and $U = (u_p, u_{p+1}, \cdots, u_{T})^T$.
Now this is a standard problem in linear algebra, as I commented above:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Y \simeq XB \implies X^TY = X^TXB \implies B = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY,
\end{aligned}
$$
the usual least squares estimator. When you code this up, you will of course use the most numerically-stable pseudoinverse that you can instead of the real inverse of the matrix.

I will note that, in my own work, the only time I do *not* use least squares to estimate a VAR model is when I want to incorporate prior assumptions. I will briefly outline an example model for you. 
For example, suppose that we have some beliefs about covariance matrix $\Sigma$, as well as beliefs about the mean of the coefficient matrix $B$. Then we can define a simple hierarchical model as 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sigma \sim \mathrm{Log}\mathcal{N}(0, 1)\\
\Sigma \sim \mathrm{LKJ}(\sigma, \eta=1)\\
B \sim \mathcal{MN}(\mu, 1)\\
Y \sim \mathcal{N}(XB, \Sigma).
\end{aligned}
$$
Here we have introduced the [LKJ distribution](https://docs.pymc.io/api/distributions/multivariate.html#pymc3.distributions.multivariate.LKJCholeskyCov), which is a sensible choice for priors over covariance matrices, and the matrix-normal distribution $\mathcal{MN}(\mu, \sigma)$ with 
mean matrix $\mu$.

Answer (score 1):

> It is not possible to use ordinary least square method since the
>   observations are not independent.

This statement is false - it is possible to use Ordinary Least Squares providing that the residuals have been corrected for **serial correlation**, or correlation between the residuals over time.

Serial correlation itself can be detected through use of the Durbin-Watson test.

```
H0: No serial correlation present

HA: Serial correlation present
```

The Durbin Watson statistic is calculated as follows:

[image: durbin watson]

Let us consider the following example. Suppose we wish to use an OLS regression to determine the relationship between oil prices and fluctuations in the S&P 500 stock market index.

Initally, the following model is generated using R:

```
SP500 Prices = Intercept + Oil Prices

Call:
lm(formula = gspc ~ oil)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-195.309  -46.802    6.726   45.612  139.918 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1768.1278    20.2744   87.21   <2e-16 ***
oil            6.5421     0.4488   14.58   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 70.44 on 499 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2986,Adjusted R-squared:  0.2972 
F-statistic: 212.5 on 1 and 499 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

However, this has not yet been tested (or corrected if necessary for serial correlation).

```
> dwtest(reg1)

Durbin-Watson test

data:  reg1
DW = 0.047108, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true autocorrelation is greater than 0
```

Next, we test the model for the presence of serial correlation using the Durbin-Watson test. With a p-value below 0.05 as shown, this is an indication that serial correlation is present in the model and needs to be remedied.

To this end, the time series is differenced and the ACF and PACF plots are generated:

**ACF**

[image: acf]

**PACF**

[image: pacf]

Given a sudden drop in lags in the partial autocorrelation function, this indicates the presence of an AR(1) time series. In this regard, the Cochrane-Orcutt method is used to correct for the serial correlation.

```
> orcuttreg1
Cochrane-orcutt estimation for first order autocorrelation 

Call:
lm(formula = gspc ~ oil)

 number of interaction: 4
 rho 0.977051

Durbin-Watson statistic 
(original):    0.04711 , p-value: 4.902e-107
(transformed): 2.08847 , p-value: 8.393e-01

 coefficients: 
(Intercept)         oil 
1811.922439    5.737714
```

With a new p-value of **0.8393**, this indicates that the serial correlation has been eliminated.

In summary, time series data **can** be modelled with OLS - **providing** that serial correlation has been corrected for.

Comment: Can this procedure also be used for hierarchical models? If so, how would I do it? It seems that there is basically no information on the internet on regression with hierarchical time series. Maybe, because it is as straight forward as was you described?